# Changing at Berlin Zoologischer Garten station

Tags: public-transport, short-connections, berlin, train-stations

At Berlin Zoologischer Garten railway station, how long does it take to change from long-distance trains to a subway train?

My ticket says that I have 7 minutes to change from platform 2 to U9. I'm not sure if that's realistic at moderate walking speed.

Comment: Sounds realistic enough to me. But is it even important for you to catch that exact U9 train? There will be another one a few minutes later ... and then another one. You ticket will not be restricted to a specific train.

Comment: Thanks. Probably not the exakt train, but on the return trip I have to catch a specific long-distance train, coming from the subway. But I guess you're right about the ticket not being restricted to a specific subway train, so I could take an earlier one to not miss the long-distance connection.

Comment: And on the return trip you will have first-hand experience with the transfer and how it compares to your walking speed.

Comment: Going back to Zoo station with the subway to catch a long distance train, I would definitely plan more than 7 minutes for the transfer. The subways in Berlin are usually reliable, but the transfer is tight if you are not well known at the station and you don't want to miss your train if the subway is two minutes delayed.

Comment: The way from the subway to a rapid-transit train should be easy in 7 minutes. Up one flight of stairs, follow the signs to the tunnel, up another flight of stairs, a short walk to the stairs to the rapid-transit platform. The key difference is that one doesn't have to orient towards the right set of stairs on the rapid-transit platform. From the subway to the regional trains is a slightly longer distance on the ground floor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible but not certain if you are a reasonably healthy adult without heavy luggage.

- Step out of of the regional or rapid-transit train on the upper level. Take the stairs to ground level. Two minutes, maybe.
- Walk to on the ground level towards the stairs to the subway. That makes the difference, depending on which stairs you took from the upper level. One to five minutes.
- Walk down the stairs, though a short corridor, down another set of stairs to the subway platform. Two to three minutes.

And as Henning pointed out, if you miss one subway there will be a next one. The frequency depends on the time of day and day of week.

Comment: More specifically: The entrance to U9 is at the southern end of the station and subway trains will arrive at a frequency from 3 minutes (daytime) to ten minutes (midnightish)